# Why is List.foldBack as fast as List.fold

Tags: performance, list, f#

"Lists in F# are implemented as singly linked lists, which means that operations that access only the head of the list are O(1), and element access is O(n)." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx

Considering this, List.foldBack, which accesses elements from the last to the first element, should be notable slower than List.fold. However, I cannot confirm this by tests:

```
let f acc x = acc + x
List.fold f 100 [1 .. 5000000] ;;
List.foldBack f [1 .. 5000000] 100;;

#time

> List.fold f 100 [1 .. 5000000] ;;
Real: 00:00:01.379, CPU: 00:00:01.468, GC gen0: 29, gen1: 26, gen2: 2
val it : int = 1647668740
> List.foldBack f [1 .. 5000000] 100;;
Real: 00:00:01.417, CPU: 00:00:01.500, GC gen0: 28, gen1: 25, gen2: 2
val it : int = 1647668740
>
```

Why does List.foldBack perform equally to List.fold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs) for `List.foldBack` you can see that it converts the list into an array and then iterates over it from the end applying the accumulator function to get the result.

Comment: Cool, I was too lazy to search for the sources, did not know it is that easy available. Thx a lot.